# Add and remove Json object from dynamic gpath input

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to add and remove the key from JSON object where input is Gpath expression.

Input json

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": {"data" :["GML", "XML"]}
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Input Gpath expression list

```
["glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.Abbrev",
"glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossSee"]
```

Here is the code I am trying using groovy jsonSlurper.

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
    gpathList.each{gpath->

        json.$gpath.remove()

    }
```

This doesnt remove the json key object.

Can anyone help!

Comment: write working code, then replace some parts of it with Eval.me function call, that could evaluate groovy code from string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample, based on your code snippets, with explanation below.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonString = """
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": {"data" :["GML", "XML"]}
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}"""

def gpathList = ["glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.Abbrev", "glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossSee"]

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

List splitPathAroundLastDot(String gpath) {
    int lastDotIndex = gpath.lastIndexOf('.')
    String path = gpath[0..lastDotIndex-1]
    String token = gpath[lastDotIndex+1..gpath.size()-1]
    [path,token]
}

gpathList.each{ gpath ->
    String path, token
    (path, token) = splitPathAroundLastDot(gpath)
    Eval.me( 'json', json , "json.${path}.remove('${token}')")
}

println json
```

When you try `json.$gpath` it is interpreted like a map lookup of `json["$gpath"]` and returns null, as that element is not there.

Even if you use the full path, and you could do this, you would end with a String, which has no `remove()` method, i.e.

```
println json.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.Abbrev.getClass()
```

will print class java.lang.String. So to do what you wish, you  should  back up one step in the json document, for this, we split the gpath with  the `splitPathAroundLastDot` method.

To evaluate the gpath on the json document, the `Eval.me` method can be used, binding the value of json to the json variable, and removes the element from the map.